# How there are so many late answers in queue for review?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, answers

Today i have seen there are so many late answers in queue which is answered long time before.

How it is possible?

[image]

Comment: And most of them are years old. Some bug?

Comment: As I recall, there is a method for Stack Exchange staff to force questions back to queues, in code or from their user interface. I don't know if this is the case, and why it should happen. Suspending a user, which means forcing the user's reputation back to 1 has some side effects on review queues, but I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a well-known, but temporary issue: [Raise the rep bar on late answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/1438)

The change took effect going back to the start of the site, but once all the current reviews are completed, the effect of the change should be only a few extra answers on the queue every now and then. It should not be a continual flood of tasks like you see here.

Sorry about the alarm.